# How to execute a function with the Hash(#) in URI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, url-rewriting

For example if I have two js functions in my HTML page named `func1()` and `func2()`. My question is how can I execute `func1()` when someone visits `/url/to/the/page#tag1` and/or similarly `func2()` when someone visits `/url/to/the/page#tag2`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems to be pretty easy

Comment: If there's a global variable with name `window.location.hash` and it's a function then execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's very simple! you could have found it with just googling it but basically, you have just to use the global window hash string and according to its value you invoke the function you need:

```
if(window.location.hash === '#tag1') {
  func1()
} else if (window.location.hash === '#tag2'){
  func2()
}
```

**Updated Version: (dangerous & slow)**

```
var number = window.location.hash.split('#tag').pop(); //return 1
if(window.location.hash === '#tag' + number) {
eval("func" + number + "()");
}
```

you should avoid using eval as it opens security vulnerabilities and can allow attackers to run malicious code on the user's machine. You can read more about the eval function and why you should never use it on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval_needlessly!)

Comment: And if there are 20 tags...?

Comment: Andreas is right, this scales pretty badly

Comment: if you have 20 tags to run 20 different functions you should be doing something wrong by design. I don't see the point to scale this and if you are still trying to do something bad like this you will end up using bad practices like the eval() function and you will end up with a pretty bad code, to say the least.

Comment: @Andreas I edited Hamed answer, with updated version, it's kinda dynamic, I wrote it blindly, but it can be dynamic..

Comment: @HamedBaatour why you think `eval` is a bad practice?

Comment: @Pedram _Your_ update won't work (which may attract downvotes... hence you should be really careful when editing someone else answer).